# How to secure resources with Casbin based on multiple groups membership

Tags: casbin

What is the best option to implement such security in Casbin?
I have several `folders`, each of them has its own security (i.e. the `users` allowed to accede it)
But that's not enough, the `action` a `user` is allowed to performed in a `folder` depends on `user`'s `group`

As an example:
`alice` can be `admin` for `folder1` so she can `read` and `write` within it
`alice` can be `user` for `folder2` so she can only `read`

I was thinking of using 1 `group` per `role` (`user`, `admin`) and 1 group per `folder`, however this is not fine because once a `user` is assigned a `role`, he cannot change

I looked at RBAC with domains and this can work until I duplicate all my policies for each `folder` (yeah, all `users` will always have the same rights in `folder`...) because domain must be part of the policy itself

Do you have any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please send a GitHub issue to Casbin repo.